Yolov7 Training Slow on RTX3060
Im trying to train a custom model with 1 class and around roughly 45k image. Doing 100 epochs it took 2 days to get to epoch 17.
Here are the parameters I used:
python train.py --workers 1 --device 0 --batch-size 8 --epochs 100 --img 640 640 --data data/coco_last_training.yaml --hyp data/hyp.scratch.custom.yaml --cfg cfg/training/yolov7_last_training.yaml --name yolov7-custom --weights yolov7

I changed loss_ota to 0.
line 31 loss_ota: 1 # use ComputeLossOTA, use 0 for faster training
in hyp.scratch.custom.yaml file.
I changed compute_loss_ota to compute_loss
loss, loss_items = compute_loss(pred, targets.to(device), imgs)  # loss scaled by batch_size

in the train.py file.
